# Changes in Swift 1.2 that confusing me

Tags: swift, objective-c-nullability

I updated Xcode to 6.3, and found there’s some new error in my codes with new Swift 1.2.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success:Bool!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    if !(error != nil) {
        println("sign up successfully")

        var loginAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up", message: "Sign Up Succeeded", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        self.presentViewController(loginAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        loginAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style:
```

I got this error:

> Cannot invoke signUpInBackgroundWithBlock with an argument list of type ((Bool!, NSError!) -> void)

How can I fix it?

Another one

```
@IBAction func endend(sender: AnyObject) {        
    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text）{  
            (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if user != nil {
                println("login chenggong")
                var tlvc = TimelineViewControllerTableViewController()                
                self.presentViewController(tlvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                println("failed")
            }        
        }    
    }
}
```

I got this error :

> “UITextField” does not have member named “text”.

And I got 3 errors that about `}`, it says

> Expected “,” separator.
>
> Expected expression in list of expressions.
>
> Expected “)” in expressions.

I can ran my app before Swift 1.2, but now...

Comment: `if !(error != nil)` would be written more sensibly as `if error == nil` Could you also show us the declaration of the `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` method?

Comment: you are missing colon after username

Comment: I can’t find where’s username you just mentioned. But thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username.text as String!, password: password.text as String!){
                (loggedInuser: PFUser?, signupError: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to Edit > Convert... > To Latest Swift Syntax...

There are several language syntax changes in the new release, so Apple included a tool to help migrate older Swift code. From what I've been reading it's largely useful but doesn't always solve 100% of the problems. Hopefully it'll at least reduce the number of errors you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

For Parse sign up blocks, the Swift 1.2 compiler does not like it when you force unwrap the boolean success parameter.

Removing the '!' after 'success:Bool' should remove the errors you are getting.

Try changing:

```
 user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{(success:Bool!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
```

To:

```
 user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{(success:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
 user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{(success:Bool!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
```

To:

```
 user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{(success:Bool?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
```